# How can I run a shell command at login time without showing a Dock entry?

Tags: startup, command-line, login-items

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run something automatically when the system boots or a use logs on?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-to-run-something-automatically-when-the-system-boots-or-a-use-logs-on)

I need to automatically run a command when I log in but I don't want to add an item to the Dock. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If that's really a command, not app, then you do this by deploying launchd, Apple's standard daemon/agent manager.
Creating plist files by hand is error-prone, I suggest you to use Lingon.app
It used to be free, now it isn't anymore, but instead available on AppStore (if you're using the latest OS X 10.6.6).