# Running a command whenever Mac boots up with launchctl/plist

Tags: startup, launchd, plist

I need to run `nohup nice synergys -f --config ~/bin/conf/synergy.conf &` command whenever the computer boots up.

As is written in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-to-run-something-automatically-when-the-system-boots-or-a-use-logs-on), I came up with the following plist code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>synergy</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>nohup nice /usr/bin/synergys -f --config /Users/USER/bin/conf/synergy.conf &</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And, ran this command.

```
launchctl load ./synergy.plist
```

However, I got this error message.

```
launchctl: no plist was returned for: ./synergy.plist
launchctl: no plist was returned for: ./synergy.plist
nothing found to load
```

What's wrong with my plist? Or is my launchctrl command wrong in options?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The immediate problem is that your .plist file isn't correctly formatted -- the contents of `<string>...</string>` should be encoded with HTML entities, i.e. `&` needs to be encoded as `&amp;` (note: you can check the format of .plist files with `plutil -lint filename.plist`).  But there are some other changes that need to be made...

Starting programs with launchd is rather different than starting them from a shell.  The biggest difference is that from the shell, you want the program to go into the background and run independently of the shell, so you wrap it in `nohup ... &`.  With launchd, it's actually best for the program to stay in the "foreground" so launchd can keep an eye on it.

Also, the elements of ProgramArguments won't get parsed by a shell, so listing the command and its arguments with spaces between them doesn't work -- make each argument a separate element of the array.

Here's my stab at a synergy .plist.  I haven't tested this, so it may need a little tweaking to work properly (see notes below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.synergy</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/synergys</string>
        <string>-f</string>
        <string>--config</string>
        <string>/Users/USER/bin/conf/synergy.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The last two keys above deal with how launchd should react if/when the synergys program exits.  By default, it kills any surviving subprocesses and launches a new instance; these two keys supress both parts, which may or may not be what you want.  Also, one thing this doesn't do that your version with `nohup` does is redirect stdin and stdout to nohup.out (in case the terminal goes away); instead IIRC launchd logs things that get sent to them.  If synergys is in the habbit of sending output, you might want to add something like this to the .plist:

```
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
```

Also, as mankoff said, you should put this in ~/Library/LaunchAgents so it'll be autoloaded every time you log in.  Oh, and you should probably add a `local.` prefix to the filename (as I did with the label) to conform to the reverse-DNS naming convention.

Comment: OMG, thank you for this: plutil -lint filename.plist

Comment: Great tip for the plutil, very handy

Comment: What is the key `Nice` and integer `10` for?

Comment: Also is there a reason why you don't use `<key>Program</key><string>/usr/bin/synergys</string>` then pass the rest of the arguments as `<key>ProgramArguments</key><array><string>Argument_1</string><string>Argument_2</string></array>`?

Comment: @hobbes3: The `Nice` value runs the program with lowered priority, equivalent to the [nice command](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nice.1.html) in the original. The reason I didn't use `<key>Program</key>` is redundancy (and laziness): you'd have to list `/usr/bin/synergys` as the `Program` *and also* as the first element of `ProgramArguments`.