# how to create daily task for GMVault in automator

Tags: automator, script, macos

I just moved to Apple, being an experienced (i'd like to think so) Windows user.

Recently I started using GMvault (gmvault.org) to backup my Gmail account locally, but it's become a pain having to manually launch a terminal and type ./gmvault sync -t quick myemail@gmail.com

if i wanted to automate this task on Mac OSX 10.8.2, what would be the right/best way to do it? Is it using an Automator task? I've heard of Cron too..so, Im open to suggestions. What is the most correct (and maintainable) way to do this?

In windows I would've just created a .bat file and setup a Scheduled Task.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you can use cron which is more transferable knowledge since it's used also on other platforms. Or you can use LaunchDaemon which is more Macish ;)

**Cron**

Please refer to question [How do I run a cron job on a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/how-do-i-run-a-cron-job-on-a-mac)

**Launchd**

- [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ)
- short how to

  - file for service looks [like this](https://gist.github.com/3795604#file_touch_file.plist)
  - you will copy that file into `/Library/LaunchAgents`. If you want the daemon to be launched when you login, not when your computer start, just prepend `~`(home) before the path

*I am sorry for linking the code instead paste it here, but it seems i am not compatible with code adding here on apple.stack ;)*

Comment: Mailo, ok, so it seems like crontab is a way to do it..so in addition to my question, if i wanted to avoid having to type the whole path of the gmvault executable, how can i add that so i can just execute ./gmvault regardless of the current terminal directory? in windows i'd do that using the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Sry, but i don't have much experience with Cron. I usually use launch daemon. Theres you just say what is the working directory by `WorkingDirectory` tag