# script menu keeps disappearing from menu bar

Tags: macos, applescript, menu-bar

The script menu (and only the script menu) keeps disappearing from my menu bar (MacBook Air). It happens on my current Mojave, but has been happening through previous OS as well.

I know how to open the Script Editor and change the preference so that it reappears. I know that it stays on for some time; but I have no clue how long, and why it disappears.

I don't want to do dig into the SE preference every time I want to use a script. The whole thing is about to be saving time!

This community has been informative in the past, so I thought I'd drop this quick challenge here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this following **AppleScript** code works on macOS Monterey.

Save this following **AppleScript** code as an .app or create an **Automator Quick Action**.  It will automatically put the Script Menu back in the menubar.

```
tell application "AppleScript Utility"
    if not Script menu enabled then
        set Script menu enabled to true
        set application scripts position to top
        set show Computer scripts to false
    end if
end tell
```

*You can obviously change the individual options to whatever you want.*

Comment: That looks like it should work fine on other OS as well – likely all the way back to Classic! It's nasty that we have to use a workaround like this, but all is not perfect in the world. I think combining it with running something like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/how-do-i-run-a-cron-job-on-a-mac) every 15 days would make it relatively hands off.