# Automatically delete a folder daily

Tags: applescript, folders, launchd, macos

Is there a way to automatically have a folder deleted every day at 4am?

I'm running 10.6.7.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-othe/3047#3047

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Appplescript & iCal

Open Applescript and enter the following code:

```
tell application "Finder"
  delete folder "folder" of home
end tell
```

Replacing **folder** with the folder you want to delete, and save the file.

If the folder you want to delete is outside home directory, (for example the folder /Users) then replace the delete line with:

```
delete folder "Users" of startup disk
```

Then open iCal and create a new recurring event at the time you want and as an alarm choose **Run Script** and select the applescript you created.

---

### Cron

Open Terminal.app and enter:

```
crontab -e
```

There to the file opened, add the following line

```
0    4       *       *       *       rm -rf /Users/USER/folder
```

replacing **/Users/USER/folder** with the **full path** of your folder and save the file.

---

### Launchd

Create a new text document, and paste the following code:

```
rm -rf /Path/to/Folder
```

Let's call it script.sh

Based on this [article](http://blog.mattbrock.co.uk/2010/02/25/moving-from-cron-to-launchd-on-mac-os-x-server/), create another new text document and paste the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>Recurring Folder Deletion</string>
  <key>UserName</key>
  <string>nuc</string>
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/path/to/script.sh</string>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>4</integer>
  </dict>
  <key>Debug</key>
  <false/>
  <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Replace **nuc** with your account username, and **/path/to/script.sh** with the full path of the script we created on first step.

Save the file in **/Library/LaunchDaemons/** as **my_rfd.plist**.

Finally, launch Terminal.app and type:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/my_rfd.plist
```

Comment: Really nice answer. +1 for giving two explanations.

Comment: The folder isn't in my home directory - how can I delete a folder from the root of a hard drive named "Users"?

Comment: @ryan edited answer to include your request.

Comment: Considering the unknown future state of cron, It would be wonderful if you would add a launchd method of doing this as well.

Comment: @vxjasonxv launchd way added! :)

Comment: Awesome. (7 more to go..)

Answer (score 3):

[Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) is a great app for doing this type of thing.  It's not free, but it works great.

I use it to "Label" or highlight files that are have been downloaded in the last 24 hours, then to delete files from my downloads folder that are more than 7 days old.

I then have it empty my trash once a month.

This is just the basics of what can be done with Hazel, it's cool.

[I have no financial interest in Hazel]

Comment: Thanks - I have Hazel too. I also posted there trying to figure this out: http://bit.ly/dISt3G