# How to automate execution locate.updatedb by using a bash script

Tags: launchd, macos, command-line

I am looking for a bash set of commands that will enable me to schedule the execution of `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` once every day.

Please respond only with a set of command line commands, because I want to include this in a "setup" script (in order to be able to reuse it when I go to another machine).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run/stop/relaunch an application automatically, at boot/login/some other time?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-othe)

Comment: Or use the deprecated `cron`.

Comment: May I ask why you're using `slocate` instead of Spotlight? (At the command line: `mdfind`)

Comment: Just because it's the same an on other Unixes.

Comment: Depending on the OSX version, it should be rebuilt weekly. Look in /etc/periodic/weekly. You should find (on 10.5.8) 310.weekly. This rebuilds the locate database.

Comment: After further checking, 310.locate is used in Leopard, NOT Snow! I added the script 310.local to my iMac that has 10.6.8 in /etc/periodic/weekly and added the appropriate string in /etc/defaults/periodic.conf. I suppose Apple could enable this from launchctld(sp?) as could I, but I chose this way instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After additional (re)search I found an easy solution:

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`

This is also persistent, so it will run updatedb daily.

Comment: This only runs locate.updatedb weekly (every saturday morning at 3:15am).  If you want it to run daily, remove `<key>Weekday</key> <integer>6</integer>` from the StartCalendarInterval dictionary in that plist file (then unload and reload it).

Comment: Isn't there a way to run this so it is actually synced. Meaning if I delete then things get removed. Also if add, things get added.