# How to search files from command line under OS X?

Tags: finder, command-line

It seems that Apple doesn't want us to use `locate`, at it is making it so hard to setup.

If there a way to use `finder` database from the command line? Maybe I can make an alias.

I would appreciate solutions that would not require system reconfiguration, just because I don't want to repeat the process each time I upgrade the system of switch computers.

Comment: locate works fine: `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`

Comment: What is so hard? You asked this question and got an answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14836/how-to-automate-execution-locate-updatedb-by-using-a-bash-script

Comment: @mankoff yes, it works as long you are updating its database, and also cron does not work anymore, so you have to install it in launchd… so it is much easier to add `alias locate="mdfind"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `mdfind`, which uses the Spotlight database. More information on this [man page](http://ss64.com/osx/mdfind.html).