# Unable to Locate or update LocateDB Mac OS El Capitain, Sierra, High Sierra, Mojave!

Tags: macos, mac, launchd

Over the past few operating systems I've been noticing a trend, especially after Apple screwed around with the real and fake "root" user in El Capitan. Most especially, using the locate command. Whenever I try to update using the conventional:

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`

Which is prescribed by Apple when the `locate` command fails. 
I've managed to use mdfind but prefer locate because I'm looking for files in the ENTIRE system and I don't care about keywords inside of files like MDFind echos, see here for more evidence of locate working better for this task than mdfind [MDfind vs Locate](https://superuser.com/questions/693375/which-tool-is-most-flexible-for-searching-my-whole-system-locate-or-mdfind). Thanks everyone, I will continue tinkering for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a bit of tinkering and waiting to delete my question prior to posting an uneducated question, I found an old [OSXDaily article](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/02/enable-and-use-the-locate-command-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal/) that suggests another way to update the Locate DB. The command suggested is: `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` And searching for that command rather than the com.apple.locate.plist setup in launchd, I found [this lovely article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228164/is-there-a-way-to-use-update-command-to-locate-files-on-os-x-without-having-to-r) about changing the database update frequency. I however, took a somewhat different approach to updating the database, simply by adding a line to my daily crontab:

`env EDITOR=nano sudo crontab -e`

`0 12 * * * sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`.

`ctrl+x y [ENTER]`

Thanks, I hope this helps someone going through the same annoying crap.

Answer (score 1):

When running `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` the script would toss this error:

```
    shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access 
parent directories: Permission denied find: 
.: Permission denied
```

I tried enabling `root` login but the script had the same behavior.

I found I can get `locate` to search almost everywhere by modifying `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`.

Change:

`if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then`

to,

`if [ "$(id -u)" = "1" ]; then`

There is some reduction security but as far as I read if this is for your personal computer you should be alright. Here are some links providing different tests and solutions:

[https://superuser.com/questions/161183/cannot-manually-update-database-for-locate/161558](https://superuser.com/questions/237014/what-folders-are-indexed-covered-by-locate)

https://superuser.com/questions/237014/what-folders-are-indexed-covered-by-locate

Comment: What version of MacOS are you running btw? I haven't yet experienced this problem (not looking forward to experiencing it either haha..).

Comment: Update: I began to notice this after upgrading to Catalina and onwards. Thanks for this info Benjamin!