# Make a script/app run on logout

Tags: macos, script, login, login-items, user-account

We all know that Mac OS X has the very useful **Login Items** functionality which lets you, among other things, set up apps/scripts to run when you log in.

I'm looking for a way to setup a list of scripts/apps that run when I **log out**. A "Logout Items" list, if you will.
Basically, I want to write a few little cleanup scripts for myself that will run automatically when I log out or shut down.

So, I'm looking for a way to have a script (or, ideally, list of them) automatically triggered when I log out. The log out would wait for the scripts to finish (just like how the logout waits for you to click Save if an app requests it).

**Is there a way to automatically trigger (a) script(s) when I log out of Mac OS X?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run/stop/relaunch an application automatically, at boot/login/some other time?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Logout hooks were [deprecated in 10.4](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW10-BAJCGEGG), but they still work as of 10.9.

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook ~/.logouthook
echo $'#!/bin/bash\nsay a' > ~/.logouthook
chmod +x ~/.logouthook
```

The value of the LogoutHook key can only be a path to an executable and not a shell command. The logout hook is run as root.

The defaults command modifies /var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist. Adding a LogoutHook key to /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist doesn't work.

If a logout hook takes long enough to run, a gray screen is shown until the logout hook terminates. There doesn't seem to be any time limit after which logout hooks are forced to terminate.

I haven't figured out any way to run programs on logout reliably with launchd. When I tried trapping signals like EXIT, the code in the trap was only run when I logged out to the login window and not when I shut down or restarted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>test</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>trap 'echo a>/Users/username/Desktop/a;say a' EXIT;while :;do sleep 10;done</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Hmm, neither of those has worked for me. I've got [this script](http://cl.ly/1n1T043h3H2W25102Q0b), which works if I run it with `sh` (it creates that .txt file). I saved the script as /etc/rc.shutdown.local, and I added it with `defaults` as you said. Neither file was there already. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or not. I'm on 10.6.8 and LogoutHook isn't working. I'd appreciate if if you could take a look at [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/KSJaG.jpg) and let me know if something looks wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! That last one did the trick on 10.6.8. Thanks! One note though: it doesn't work with Lion :(

Comment: Both methods work fine on my Mountain Lion (10.8.2) machine, even when shutting down or rebooting. Note that the LoginHook/LogoutHook hooks run in the context of the _root_ user, and that they are _single, system-wide_ hooks, and that the login hook runs _synchronously_ - much earlier than per-user launch agents; similarly, the logout hook runs earlier than a per-user launch agent that uses the EXIT-trap method. There are cases where _only_ the hooks work; for instance, if you want to mute the sound on shutdown in order to suppress the Mac's startup sound, only the LogoutHook works reliably.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a non-deprecated way to do it:

1. Open the "Script Editor" app
2. Paste

```bsh
    do shell script "PUT YOUR START SCRIPT PATH HERE"
    
    on quit
        do shell script "PUT YOUR STOP SCRIPT PATH HERE"
        continue quit
    end quit
```

3. File > Save, Select **Application** and **Stay open after run handler** and Save
4. System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items tab > + button
5. Add the application and mark it as Hidden

To hide it from the Dock:

1. Right-click the application and select Show package content
2. Open Info.plist and add

```xml
<key>NSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

Comment: Love this. Simple and adequate for my needs. And not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

[Script Timer](http://www.appsandmore.com/script_timer.htm) is a good choice for this. It can run at logout, login, and much more. I'd go with this for a simple and easy to use solution. It has a simple GUI:

[image: Triggered action]

There are two things you need to note about Script Timer. One, it is *not* free. It costs $12, but I personally think it's worth it. Two, it isn't fully compatible with Lion, but they have promised a free update as soon as they've made it compatible.

Comment: This is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a Mac application from your script using something like [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) and then add it to Login Items like any other application.

Answer (score 0):

[Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) can run a script when a user logs out. This is a commercial product and it supports the latest macOS.

[image: Power Manager run a script on log out Schedule Assistant task]

Earlier versions [required using the event editor](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2012-03-09-how-to-run-a-shell-script-when-logging-out/), but a Schedule Assistant task is now included for running scripts at log in and out.

I wrote Power Manager, so feel free to ask technical questions about its implementation. In the case of log out triggered events, Power Manager does not poll for changes in user state but instead is notified of user changes by macOS. This approach is more efficient that having a script looping/polling.