# Run script when logged out?

Tags: snow-leopard, login, login-screen

Is it possible to run a script *when and **only when*** a user is logged out? Why I want to do this is so I can change the login message (`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow LoginwindowText "Message"`). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean "upon logout" or "while logged out"?

Comment: @JRobert While logged out

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run/stop/relaunch an application automatically, at boot/login/some other time?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth)

Comment: See [Make a script/app run on logout](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16831/4408).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Machints has got a sample script available [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2006081701162739) to write the logon and logoff events to a log file.

You basically need to write your script, give it execute rights and then add it to the `LogoutHook` event:

> sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow \ LogoutHook /usr/local/bin/logoutscript

For some more advanced script you can also have a look [here](http://www.afp548.com/netboot/mactips/scripts.html)

**Alternative solution**

Have a look at the [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) services. It's the built in service management system used by OSX. Some suggestions are to have launchd monitor a file, and using the logoutHook above, touch the file, which will trigger launchd to run. In the launchd job you can sleep the process for a few seconds to ensure that logout is completed.

Not the ideal solution, but could work.

Comment: That wasn't what I was looking for. Instead of running while I was logged off, it ran while I was logging off.

Comment: @CoffeeRain Added a potentail workaround. Not entirely sure how vaiable it but worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your login screen text, no need to run a script if this is a one-time or infrequent change. You have to add the key

[image]

to /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist either with a text editor or by a terminal command which does the same thing.  [This article](http://osx411.com/index.php?/topic/6-how-to-add-text-to-os-x-login-window/page__p__6#entry6) describes both ways.

Answer (score 0):

See here for how to run a script: [How can I run/stop/relaunch an application automatically, at boot/login/some other time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth)

Have your script check if user logged in. If yes, exit. If no, do your thing.