# How can I add login and logout sounds to OS X 10.8.x?

Tags: login, audio, user-account

I would like to add login and logout sounds to my Mac. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a script like this as `~/Desktop/test` and make it executable with `chmod +x ~/Desktop/test`.

```
#!/bin/bash

afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Blow.aiff
```

You can then add a LogoutHook key to `/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist` with `sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook ~/Desktop/test`. It can be deleted with `sudo defaults delete com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook`. You can run a script at login by adding a LoginHook key or by using launchd.

See also these questions about running scripts on [logout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16825) and [login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030) and [Daemons and Services Programming Guide: Customizing Login and Logout](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW10-BAJCGEGG).

Answer (score -1):

**Just write this**  Shutdown   *maybe that will work*

```
Shutdown
```