# Show Dialog Window if User logout on High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra

When a user logout, I want to display a window. In this window should be a text (Please save your data...). After the user has pressed OK. The process logout continue. Is this possible?

```
onLogout() (
    # that works:
    if [ "$USER" != "admin" ] && [ "$USER" != "Administrator" ]; then
        rm -Rf ~/Downloads/*
        rm -Rf ~/Movies/*
        rm -Rf ~/Music/*
        rm -Rf ~/Pictures/*
        rm -Rf ~/Public/*
        rm -Rf ~/Desktop/*
    fi
    # it doesn`t work:
    res=$(osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Please save yout Data!" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 1 with icon caution with title "Important Information!"' 2>/dev/null)

        if [[ $res == *OK* ]]; then 
            # continue logout?
        else
            # break logout?
        fi
    exit
)
trap 'onLogout' SIGINT SIGHUP SIGTERM
while true; do
    sleep 86400 &
    wait $!
done
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you need here? Are you looking for a notice the user needs to see *before* they logout? Is it informational only or do the need to confirm it/press a button? Or is it a notice which is displayed *after* the logout is completed (so it is visible to whoever looks at the screen *after* the logout)?

Comment: @nohillside If before this may be helpful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74956/how-can-i-automatically-run-an-applescript-on-shutdown-or-logout

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** this is possible.

You can use the "User Policy Banner" feature.

Although used mainly in cafes and other public places to make user agree to a ToC this feature can be used to create a dialog box.

From [the related Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202277):

A policy banner is a banner that you can display at the login window that requires a user to acknowledge it before proceeding.

> ### Create a banner
>
> You can set a login message that appears at the login screen of your
>   Mac. You can also set a "policy" banner to display a longer message
>   that you must accept before you can log in. This can be useful in
>   situations where you need users to agree to or acknowledge terms or
>   conditions before using the computer, such as an Acceptable Use
>   Policy.
>
> Use these steps to create a policy banner:
>
> 1. Create a plain text (.txt) or rich text (.rtf) document named PolicyBanner that contains your banner.
> 2. Copy the PolicyBanner file to the /Library/Security/ folder.
>
> The next time you restart the computer, the banner you created appears
>   when you would normally see the login screen.

The banner will look like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hopefully as soon as refers to after logout.

Comment: Good answer, learnt something new here. But I'm not sure the answer matches the problem the OP has :-)

Comment: @nohillside Well since there was not much detail here I went with the technicals of what they were saying. "As soon as user logs off" is referring to the time post logout has completed therefore this should be adequate. But I do see how with more details this may be not the correct answer :)

Comment: I need a text window when the user has logout! Not Login!

Comment: @steffus It works either way.