# Possible to add a password to the guest account on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, password, user-account, guest-account

I have a very precocious four-year-old who absolutely adores computers. We gave him his own login with which we control his access carefully.

The problem is the guest account. It requires no password, so regardless of the parental controls on his account, he can always log on as guest.

Applying parental controls to the guest account defeats the purpose, as I want my houseguests to be able to use it anytime they like. I would just give them the password on their arrival.

I suppose I could disable the guest account, and create a separate account which would basically be a normal user account except named "Visitor" and with a password. But I like the automatic cleanup of the guest account, and, well, that's kind of what it's there for.

But I'm still holding out hope: is there any way to add a password to the guest account?

Comment: "You actually can set a password for the guest account. Use `sudo passwd guest` from the terminal" see [this answer below](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127752/116146)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, by design the Guest users are Guests (temporary visitors). They do not require password and you can not set one.

Your only other alternative is to set up a user account with password.

However, that could bring trouble and I would not trust the 4 years one, he/she could find how to change password and then you are locked out :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'll set up an alternative user account for my visitors, and I can write a script to clean up after them per the recommendations here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16825/make-a-script-app-run-on-logout

Comment: I don't think you can be locked out if you have an administrator account (unless the other account is also administrator), since you can always force-change the other account's password.

Answer (score 6):

You actually *can* set a password for the guest account.

Use `sudo passwd guest` from the terminal.

Comment: it works on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: For newbies, press **Cmd + Space**, then type **terminal**. After typing the command, you will have to type _your_ password 1st (or the _administrator_ one) to access it. Then you'll type the new password for guest and confirm it.