# Is there a Mac equivalent for UDEV folder on linux?

Tags: mac, bash

I am writing a script which should backup my Documents folder onto a USB stick. I want the script to be executed every time I connect the USB stick. I found a solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189383/bash-script-to-detect-when-my-usb-is-plugged-in-and-to-then-sync-it-with-a-direc) But it seems like I can't find the folder where to put the rule.

So **does anyone know where I could find a udev or rules folder?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash drive autorun script on Mac](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19176/flash-drive-autorun-script-on-mac)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

udev doesn't exist on OS X. As an alternative, you can use the `diskutil activity` command to continuously monitor disks being mounted or ejected. The `diskutil` man page says

> Continuously display system-wide disk manipulation activity as reported by the Disk Arbitration framework until interrupted with a signal (e.g. by typing Control-C). This can be useful to watch system-wide activity of disks coming on-line or being ejected, volumes on disks being mounted or unmounted, volumes being renamed, etc.

Whilst running the above command and plugging in (then removing) my WD Elements USB drive, I get this output, which could be parsed (even though the man page says not to) to find, say, `DiskMountApproval` and `DiskDisappeared` to get the volume name and when the disk was added and removed.

```
***DiskPeek ('disk2') Time=20120331-11:56:22.7716
***DiskPeek ('disk2s1') Time=20120331-11:56:23.0801
***DiskAppeared ('disk2', DAVolumePath = '<null>', DAVolumeKind = '<null>', DAVolumeName = '<null>') Time=20120331-11:56:23.0810
***DiskMountApproval ('disk2s1', DAVolumePath = '<null>', DAVolumeKind = 'hfs', DAVolumeName = 'Elements') Comment=Approving Time=20120331-11:56:23.0820
***DiskAppeared ('disk2s1', DAVolumePath = 'file://localhost/Volumes/Elements/', DAVolumeKind = 'hfs', DAVolumeName = 'Elements') Time=20120331-11:56:23.2574
***DAIdle (no DADiskRef) Time=20120331-11:56:23.2576
***DiskUnmountApproval ('disk2s1', DAVolumePath = 'file://localhost/Volumes/Elements/', DAVolumeKind = 'hfs', DAVolumeName = 'Elements') Comment=Approving Time=20120331-11:56:44.2338
***DiskDescriptionChanged ('disk2s1', DAVolumePath = '<null>') Time=20120331-11:56:44.4515
***DAIdle (no DADiskRef) Time=20120331-11:56:44.4518
***DiskEjectApproval ('disk2') Comment=Approving Time=20120331-11:56:44.4542
***DiskDisappeared ('disk2', DAVolumePath = '<null>', DAVolumeKind = '<null>', DAVolumeName = '<null>') Time=20120331-11:56:50.1964
***DiskDisappeared ('disk2s1', DAVolumePath = '<null>', DAVolumeKind = 'hfs', DAVolumeName = 'Elements') Time=20120331-11:56:50.1970
***DAIdle (no DADiskRef) Time=20120331-11:56:50.1972
```

Answer (score 2):

udev is Linux specific, so you won't find that in OS X.

You'll need to look for alternative ways of writing your script, e.g. using [diskutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600514/alternative-to-udev-functionality-on-osx).