# Setting a automator action to run everyday

Tags: applescript, automator

I have an automator action that downloads file from our server. Easy enough to setup but can't quite sort out how to set it so it will operate automatically at a certain time everyday. Tried hooking it with iCal but that didn't seem to work. Any assistance or pointing in the right direction is appreciated

Comment: Well -- figured this one out! Overlooked that you could set iCal to open a file at a certain time. Set it to open up the Automator action *works perfectly!. Even when iCal isn't open.

Comment: please add this as answer and accept it. Not only is it [perfectly OK to accept your own answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/), it helps keeping the site tidy by filing your question as “answered” (while it is, and will remain, “open” as it is now).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run/stop/relaunch an application automatically, at boot/login/some other time?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth)

Comment: An alternative is good old crontab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well -- figured this one out! Overlooked that you could set iCal to open a file at a certain time. Set it to open up the Automator action *works perfectly!. Even when iCal isn't open. –

Answer (score 1):

You can save an automator workflow as a Plugin, and it becomes an actual alarm action available in iCal.

Here's a doc for an older version of Automator.
http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Automator/1.0/en/ensm2063.html

In Snow Leopard/Lion, when you create a new Automator event you can choose "iCal Alarm"