# How to synchronize QuickTime video playback with 3 different Macs?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, video, quicktime

Do you know a method to play three (QuickTime) videos in sync on three different machines? At least I would trigger the space bar to start them in sync.

Comment: If the computers are near each other and you have a Bluetooth keyboard, have you tried pairing it with all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Multiscreener?
I have used this in the past and worked flawlessly for 3 day runs.
http://www.zachpoff.com/software/multiscreener/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well synchronized it would be, but you could try using `at` (or [launchd or cron](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth)) to run an osascript command at a specified time.

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
at 16:12 <<< 'osascript -e "tell app \"QuickTime Player\" to play document 1"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! (never heard of osascript, I will do a research)
Anyway, I think that the three macs will have different loading time for loading quicktime application and the videos, so I think it will be hardly synchronize with this command.. It would be very good if I find the method just for triggering for example the space bar when videos are loaded.. I will continue my research :-)

Comment: The command just tells QuickTime Player to play a video that has been opened before. You could try adding something like `sleep 0.1; ` before it on faster computers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use VLC to push the video out as a UDP Multicast stream (or on HTTP).  You can then receive the stream on all machines.