# Is there some way to keep the mail.app always opened?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Is there some way to the make mail.app open on boot, and maintain always opened? Like a service in linux. It would be perfect if it continues to run even when not showing on Dock or on "<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>", but still showing notifications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run/stop/relaunch an application automatically, at boot/login/some other time?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth)

Comment: Let's split this into two questions. How to run in the background. Can running apps (or the system) be hacked/changed to not show in the Dock or task switcher. Even if you need help synthesizing both answers into one app / workflow. Getting answers to each piece is better than chaining together these tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers mentioned, you can just add it to login items:

[image]

There is a bug (?) where Mail is not hidden at login even if the hide checkbox is checked though. And it doesn't prevent you from quitting Mail manually.

You could also add this to the crontab (`EDITOR=nano crontab -e`):

```
* * * * * open -jga mail
```

Or using launchd, save this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/keep_mail_open.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>keep_mail_open</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>     
        <string>open</string>
        <string>-jga</string>
        <string>mail</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You can load the plist with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/keep_mail_open.plist` or by logging out and back in.

This would disable ⌘Q:

```
defaults write -app mail NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Quit Mail' '\0' && killall Mail
```

Adding `<key>LSUIElement</key><true/>` to an Info.plist normally hides an application from the Dock, but it also removes the menu bar. Since 10.8 some applications (apparently including Mail) crash on launch if the Info.plist is modified though.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!
But, what does the '-j' argument does?
It isn't specified in the 'man open'

Comment: It's only shown in `open -h`, but it opens an application hidden.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click your mail icon in the dock you can choose Options > Open at Login.
This way Mail will always open after a reboot / power failure.
Speaking of power failure, in your system preferences under Energy Saver you have a checkbox for "Start up automatically after power failure".

I'm not aware of an option to keep your mail.app hidden from the dock when it's running.

Answer (score 1):

Either right-click or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on the Mail icon in the Dock, and select `Options->Open at Login`. To hide the icon, right-click and select `Hide`, or when Mail is active hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Notifications should still show in the Notification Center, but clicking on one to open it may unhide Mail.app.

AFAIK, hiding an app does not remove it from the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> menu.