# How to synchronize contents of two external drives?

Tags: hard-drive, data-synchronization, external-disk

I have two external hard drives (ExFAT formatted) which I need to keep in sync.  Specifically, drive B must mirror the contents of drive A and drive A must not be modified.  How can I do this without having to do a *full* copy of drive contents every time?  I'm on OS X 10.10.

This is simply for periodically backing up the contents of drive A.

Comment: Not sure if you want to invest in a nas, but I use a synology DS214+ nas with 2 drives in it. One drive is a backup of the other. Raid.

Comment: @Jules - a RAID is not a backup

Comment: @Jules Thanks, but I'm only looking for software solutions now.

Comment: @Szabolcs Do you already use Time Machine to backup your Mac?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `rsync` like this:

```
rsync -av --delete /Volumes/DiskA/ /Volumes/DiskB
```

`--delete` option is for delete files in DiskB that was previously deleted on DiskA.

If you want to schedule it to execute periodically, I suggest you to read [How can I run/stop/relaunch an application automatically, at boot/login/some other time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth).

Comment: I was under the impression that rsync can't delete files.  It seem that's not correct then.  I don't need (or want) to schedule it, as the disks are not always connected.  I can run it manually.

Comment: Easier, just execute the command when you need to, and you are done.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `/Volumes/DiskA/` instead of `/Volumes/DiskA`?  I tested it on a small folder and it creates the folder name of the source in the destination otherwise.

Comment: You are right. My mistake.

Comment: If after running the command you don't see any changes, e.g., files that shouldn't be in DiskB are still there, try using `sudo` like this:
    
    sudo rsync -av --delete /Volumes/DiskA/ /Volumes/DiskB/

Comment: @EsdrasLopez Using `sudo` for this is **not** a good idea. It will set root file permissions on the target drive for everything, which means you might not be able to write to it as a normal user.

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` is certainly one way to go. The other is to use something like [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [CarbonCopyCloner](https://bombich.com) which can do drive cloning/mirroring. Also, [ChronoSync](http://www.econtechnologies.com/chronosync/overview.html) might be an option as well, if you need to keep track of deleted contents for any reason.

Answer (score 2):

I use DropSync and have done for ages - does what you need and more and costs $16 from the developer or $19.99 from the Mac App Store.

http://www.mudflatsoftware.com/

Comment: $8 is much more reasonable than the price of the other tools mentioned and I do prefer a graphical tool to typing in rsync commands (which carry a risk of making a typo as small as leaving off a `/` and completely messing up the harddrives).  Does it support deleting files in the destination directory?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes it does, I use it to keep an exact copy of folders from my hard drive over an ethernet connection to my wife's computer. If I delete files then sync they are deleted on her computer as well. You also get a preview of what files will be copied and which ones will be deleted before you commit to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). It's a tool that simplifies keeping two folders in sync.

Install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install unison
```

Then call it with the two drives as arguments:

```
unison /Volumes/A /Volumes/B
```

Follow the instructions and make sure to [read the manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html). There are some [tips for macOS here](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/wiki/index.php?n=Main.UnisonFAQOSSpecific). For example, I've created a preference file in `~/.unison/default.prf` with the following contents to exclude metadata and resource forks:

```
ignore = Name {Cache*,.Trash*,.VolumeIcon.icns,.HSicon,Temporary*,.Temporary*,TheFindByContentFolder}
ignore = Name {.AppleDesktop,.AppleDb,TheVolumeSettingsFolder,.Metadata,.filler,.idsff,.Spotlight,.Spotlight-V100,.DS_Store,.CFUserTextEncoding}
rsrc = false
ignore = Name .FBCIndex
ignore = Name .FBCLockFolder
```