# Check if a process is running, if not execute it again in Terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line

Is there a way to periodically check if a process is running with (probably with Apple script, or some other shell script) and if not then to execute it in Terminal?

I have a PHP script that is needs to run, but after some time it breaks, so I need to start it again.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run something automatically when the system boots or a use logs on?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-to-run-something-automatically-when-the-system-boots-or-a-use-logs-on)

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/837/automatically-relaunch-a-closed-application

Answer (score 5):

In OSX use launchd to to this. launchd will start a command at login or boot and if the process dies it will restart it.

The process is controlled by a .plist file [formatted as defined in Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) the example in that manual page is for the case you ask for.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
   http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.example.exampled</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
             <string>exampled</string>
        </array>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>
```

If you want to to start when a user logs in the this file goes in ~/Library/LaunchAgents. If when the machine boots then /Library/LaunchDaemons (which can't have access to the GUI)  but this will run as root unless you add a UserName key. (Thanks to @Gordon Davisson for the correction and a reread of [Apple definitions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html))

For ease of setting the .plist up you can use [Lingon.app](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) available from the Mac AppStore

Comment: Correction: to run it at boot, put the file in /Library/LaunchDaemons.

Comment: @jherran see [meta](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/why-was-my-edit-removing-code-formatting-reverted) and many in meta stack overflow - don't use code formatting in plain text just for code

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to do this via a shell script I'd do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROCESS=`ps A | grep PROCESS_NAME | grep -v grep`
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
        echo "not running"
        ### COMMAND TO EXECUTE HERE ###
        exit 1
fi
```

You could call that via [cron](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714) every minute or so.

Answer (score 2):

Why you need to actively poll for the script? Why not just put it in a shell script loop and restart it when it fails.

```
#!/bin/sh

let c=1
while ! php -f myscript.php; do
    echo "The script has crashed $c times so far..."
    let "c=c+1"
done
```

In the case it doesn't fail gracefully, polling for a running process won't save you either. It may as well keep running while not doing its job.